# Using apply as mapping is very slow on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to map two tables but because of the complexity it is quite hard to do it using Pandas' built in functions so I am trying to build my own.

Rules are as follows: I have a table with INDEX and Col1. I have another table with INDEX (unrelated to table1), Col1, Col2 and Col3.

My function is:

```
def funct(col1):
    result= df2['cool1'][df2['col3'] == col1].value
    if len(result) == 0:
        result= df2[df2['col2'] == col1].value
        if len(result) == 0:
        return col1
    return result[0]
```

Hopefully I wrote this right, but basically it is search for df1.col1 on df2.col3 and return df2.col1. If df2.col3 is not present then return df2.col2 and if not then simply return the input df1.col1.

I then run this using:

```
df1['col1'].apply(funct)
```

Results are correct but on df1 of length of 6000 records and df2 of maybe 100 the speed is quite slow (20-30 sec).

Comment: Do you know that in four places you switched the 'l' and the 't' in 'result', but you returned it spelled correctly?

Comment: @zondo Fixed...maybe now the question makes sense to you.

Comment: Could you create a minimal example with actual data!?

Comment: @Cleb , thing is that I would have to paste 6000 lines for you to appreciate the slowness